# Is there a way to search the HTML, JavaScript, CSS of a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I am looking for a way to search through a website for specific front-end source code: HTML, CSS and JavaScript. This is easy on a single page, but I know of no way to do it over an entire site.

It would be helpful when working for larger institutions that lack good communication. To see how things were implemented on other areas of the site, or by other front end developers (typically number in the 100s).

I don't think it is possible, but I wanted to send it up the flag pole.

Comment: so, basically, you'd like your own crawler, that reads a page and follows all links on the page and reads those pages etc. There are plenty of applications that do that - just use google

Comment: Other than manually viewing the source in a browser... you could always consider using some sort of cURL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) type of library where you could write a script that downloads web pages to somewhere (of your choosing,) and then manually (or with another script... or more functions,) search through those files.

Comment: I was unable to find anything on google, if you have any links I will click them.

I was hoping for something a little more off the shelf tan cURL, but I will check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`wget` can [recursively search](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download) a website. I haven't tried, but I imagine you could pipe its output through grep or such.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I was hoping for something already baked. But I will check this out, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Google** Developer **Console**.

Once the console is open hit '**sources**' tab and you can see the whole applications file tree, simply open a file up > hit the **{ }** to unminify and simply act is if it's any other code edit '**command / control + F**' to search!

*Check [this tut](http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/), used slightly differently here, but good way to see how to access files within console.*